# Nodemailer only working with one email address

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

First time trying to get nodemailer to work, and it does work, but only if the sending email address is my email address... I currently have this code:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Hotmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk',
      pass: 'XXXX'
    }
  });
  const mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.address, // sender address
    to: 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk', // list of receivers
    subject: req.body.address,
    html: req.body.message // html body
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    res.render('index');
  });
```

If i put in a random email address in the form and send it, I get an Error: Message Failed. Not sure if i'm missing something really obvious with this but at the moment the sender address has to match the receiver (or it could be my auth.user email) for it to work.

Has anyone had trouble with this before / can shine some light on this? Thanks

Comment: What was the error your'e getting on the console

Comment: @iambatman it's giving me:

Error: Message failed: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.

And then saying: 
SMTPConnection._formatError

Answer (score 0):

So i think i've fixed it. It doesn't seem to let emails be sent from someone who isn't authorised, so I have set the sender and receiver to my email address, and used the users email address from the form in the body of the email.

```
 const mailOptions = {
    from: 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk', // sender address
    to: 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk', // list of receivers
    subject: req.body.address,
    text: `${req.body.address} - ${req.body.message}` // html body
  };
```